# How can I use mailto in a MVC Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mailto

I am currently moving a site over to MVC with great success, but I have a couple of pages which have a `mailto` link on them.  Is there a way to get this to work with `Html.ActionLink`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` is meant to do just that, render a link to an action method URL; a `mailto:` link is a special case, a pseudo-protocol which is acted upon by the client's browser.

Just use a straight HTML anchor tag in your view, there's nothing wrong with doing that.

Answer (score 4):

```
  <a href="mailto:email@samplemeail.com?Subject=subject">LinkText</a>
```

With MVC model

```
 <a href="mailto:@Model.Email">E-mail</a>
```